# Получить название региона по точке на Яндекс картах

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Есть скрипт яндекс карт, на карте выбирается точка и адресс точки записывается в `input`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        ymaps.ready(init);

        function init() {
            var  myInput = document.getElementById("address"),
                myPlacemark,
                myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
                    center: [55.753994, 37.622093],
                    zoom: 9
                }, {
                    searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
                });


            // Слушаем клик на карте.
            myMap.events.add('click', function (e) {
                var coords = e.get('coords');

                // Если метка уже создана – просто передвигаем ее.
                if (myPlacemark) {
                    myPlacemark.geometry.setCoordinates(coords);
                }
                // Если нет – создаем.
                else {
                    myPlacemark = createPlacemark(coords);
                    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
                    // Слушаем событие окончания перетаскивания на метке.
                    myPlacemark.events.add('dragend', function () {
                        getAddress(myPlacemark.geometry.getCoordinates());
                    });
                }
                getAddress(coords);

            });

            // Создание метки.
            function createPlacemark(coords) {
                return new ymaps.Placemark(coords, {
                    iconCaption: 'поиск...'
                }, {
                    preset: 'islands#violetDotIconWithCaption',
                    draggable: true
                });
            }

            // Определяем адрес по координатам (обратное геокодирование).
            function getAddress(coords) {
                myPlacemark.properties.set('iconCaption', 'поиск...');
                ymaps.geocode(coords).then(function (res) {
                    var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0),
                        address = firstGeoObject.getAddressLine();

                    myPlacemark.properties
                        .set({
                            // Формируем строку с данными об объекте.
                            iconCaption: [
                                // Название населенного пункта или вышестоящее административно-территориальное образование.
                                firstGeoObject.getLocalities().length ? firstGeoObject.getLocalities() : firstGeoObject.getAdministrativeAreas(),
                                // Получаем путь до топонима, если метод вернул null, запрашиваем наименование здания.
                                firstGeoObject.getThoroughfare() || firstGeoObject.getPremise()
                            ].filter(Boolean).join(', '),
                            // В качестве контента балуна задаем строку с адресом объекта.
                            balloonContent: address
                        });
                    myInput.value = address;

                });
            }

        }
    </script>
```

Как здесь из API получить еще Регион точки? Например, в отдельную переменную `region`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `getAdministrativeAreas()` возвращает содержание компонентов адреса, описывающих регион.

Например, в случае адресов в Москве это "Москва", т.к. это город федерального значения, а для такого адреса как "Московская область, городской округ Лосино-Петровский, село Анискино, Весенняя улица, 4" - это уже два элемента иерархии: "Московская область" и "городской округ Лосино-Петровский"

Comment: а как его использовать в контексте моего скрипта? это метод какого объекта?

Comment: в вашем скрипте это метод firstGeoObject.getAdministrativeAreas() - он там уже используется, потому что это пример из песочницы Яндекса :)

Comment: это Вы точно подметили =) спасибо все заработало