# API Yandex извлечь область объекта через известные долготу и широту. Python

Tags: python, yandex-geocoding-api

Даны долгота и широта объектов. Необходимо через API Yandex определить регион (область\край и т.д) нахождения объекта.
Подключила api yandex. Извлекаю адрес следующим способом:

pip install yandex-geocoder

```
from decimal import Decimal
from yandex_geocoder import Client

client = Client("my_api_key")
client.address(Decimal("36.079778"), Decimal("52.982026"))
```

Вывод:'Россия, Орёл, улица Максима Горького, 82'

Мне же нужно разбить объекты по регионам нашей страны, а в данном выводе регион не указан. Вижу, что есть метод getAdministrativeAreas(), но не могу разобраться как его использовать на питонe..

Подскажите, как вывести регион нахождения объекта по заданным координатам в питоне.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/876786/Получить-название-региона-по-точке-на-Яндекс-картах